# Which API levels to load in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is each Android Studio API level a cumulative of previous levels PLUS new features for newer devices?

Example:

```
Level 22 (Android 5, Lollipop)
Level 23 (Android 6, Marshmellow)
Level ...
Level 29 (Android 10) 
Level 30 (Android 11)
Level 31
```

`Level 31` is for the new Android 12.0, but does Level 31 also include everything that preceded it, Levels 22-30?  Can I just load Level 31 and assume Android 5.1 thru Android 11 are supported from the Level 31 API?  Or must I still add Levels 22-30 to my project in order to support all those previous Android versions?

My understanding is that I must still load Levels 22-30, but I have never had clarity on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want API for an emulator, you are right, you have to add API Levels 22-30 individually from AVD manager to use those Android versions. But if you want your app to be compatible with Android devices from API 22 to 31 you just need to add SDK from SDK manager-> SDK Platforms and select API level 22 and 31 then just add minSdkVersion level 22 and targetSdkVersion level 31 in your build.gradle (Module) file.

Comment: so, to clarify: 1) to run emulator for Android 6-12 I need to add APIs 22-31 in the AVD Manager and 2) then for the app compatibility for Android 6-12, I also need to add API levels 22-31 in the SDK Manager.